# signalr common Assembly or namespace is not available

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, chat, signalr

```
 using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
 using Signalr.common;//It is not available

  namespace Chat_App.Hubs
 {
 public class ChatHub :Hub
{
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        // Call the addNewMessageToPage method to update clients.
        Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(name, message);
    }
    public void Connect(string userName)
    {

        var id = Context.ConnectionId;

        if (ConnectedUsers.Count(x => x.ConnectionId == id) == 0)
        {

            ConnectedUsers.Add(new UserDetail { ConnectionId = id, UserName = userName });

            // send to caller
            Clients.Caller.onConnected(id, userName, ConnectedUsers, CurrentMessage);

            // send to all except caller client
            Clients.AllExcept(id).onNewUserConnected(id, userName);

        }

    }
```

I want a chatapp for my website i am having signalr chat room but 
the namespace is not available,Above is the code for signal r chat app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no common assembly so you can remove that using.